# how to disable checkbox forever using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with three checkbox on it, when I click on any of the checkbox it will disable.

So if I click on the first checkbox it will disable or if I click on the first and second checkbox, if I click the second checkbox and the third checkbox it will also disable but when I refresh the page it goes back to being the default checkbox not disabled

here's my code

```js
$( "input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event){
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' value='testing one'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='testing two'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='testing three'/>
```

thank you

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday. If you want to disable it *forever*, you need a database for this. What backend script/langauge do you use?

Comment: I want to get this done using javascript or jquery

Comment: Using javascript/jQuery will not save the data *forever*. These are frontend scripts. You can store it on localStorage but if the user clears the browser, the data will be loss.

Comment: Save your disable state in localstorage of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use localStorage,if you won't clean browser cache the data will be saved on your computer forever

Answer (score 0):

Save the disabled checkboxes' indicies in localStorage, and then on page load, disable those indicies.

```js
const disabledIndicies = JSON.parse(localStorage.disabledIndicies || '[]');
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")
  .forEach((input, i) => {
    if (disabledIndicies.includes(i)) {
      input.disabled = true;
      return;
    }
    input.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(input.value);
      input.disabled = true;
      disabledIndicies.push(i);
      localStorage.disabledIndicies = JSON.stringify(disabledIndicies);
    });
  });
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' value='testing one'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='testing two'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='testing three'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='testing 4'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='testing 5'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='testing 6'/>
```

Due to SO sandboxing, it won't work in the snippet, but you can see a working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zd9yhas5/

Comment: thank for the code It works nice but can I get the value of that checkbox that has been checked

Comment: Just do `console.log(input.value);`

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript and jQuery only, you can store the data on `localStorage`

Here is an example:

```
//Get localStorage data 
var check = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('check')) || [];

//Disable all checkbox that is found on localStorage 
check.forEach(function(v) {
  $("input[value='" + v + "']").attr('disabled', true).prop('checked',true);
})

//Add event listener
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event) {
  check.push($(this).val());                            //Push the value to the array
  localStorage.setItem('check', JSON.stringify(check)); //Save the array to localStorage 
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);                       //Disable the clicked checkbox
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9js97xgt/

Comment: thank for the code It works nice but can I get the value of that checkbox that has been checked

Comment: Yes, the variable `var check` is an array that contains the values of the checked checkboxes @Randombuddy